# PHP array reformat to highchart json ob

Tags: php, arrays, json, highcharts

I am try to format an array to a JSON object that highcharts supports. My array from the database is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Group_ID] => 1
            [Name] => A line graph
            [month] => 4
            [amount] => 7700
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Group_ID] => 2
            [Name] => B Line graph
            [month] => 4
            [amount] => 390
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Group_ID] => 1 
            [Name] => A line graph
            [month] => 5
            [amount] => 5000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Group_ID] => 2
            [Name] => B line graph
            [month] => 5
            [amount] => 210
        )
)
```

I need to create an array like this to be able to create a highchart compatible JSON object:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => A revenue
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [4] => 7700 //amount for the fourth month
                    [5] => 5000 //amount for the fifth month
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => B revenue
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [4] => 390 //amount for the fourth month
                    [5] => 210 //amount for the fifth month
                )
        )
)
```

I have managed to come up with this array using my foreach but I cant seem to find a way to do it correctly:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => A line graph
            [amount] => 7700
            [month] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => B line graph
            [amount] => 390
            [month] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => A line graph
            [amount] => 5000
            [month] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => B line graph
            [amount] => 210
            [month] => 5
        )

)
```

My foreach:

```
 foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $r[] = [
            'name' => $value['Line_GraphName'],
            'data' => $value['amount'],
            'month' => $value['month']
        ];
 }
```

Comment: AbraCadaver has the right answer, I would just point out for future reference in your foreach loops, don't get the $key unless you're going to use it. You're just wasting resources at that point. Small thing, for sure.

Comment: Thank you for that Doyle Lewis, had no idea on that :0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create it very simply like this:

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $r[$value['Group_ID']]['name'] = $value['Line_GraphName']; 
    $r[$value['Group_ID']]['data'][$value['month']] = $value['amount'];
}
```

- Loop and create a result with `Group_ID` as the key and add the `name` key and value
- Add `data` array and append `month` as key and `amount` as value

If you don't like having `Group_ID` as the key and want to re-index:

```
$r = array_values($r);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `array_walk` and `array_values` functions:

```
$result = [];
array_walk($data, function($v) use(&$result) {
    $key = $v['Group_ID'] . $v['Name'][0];  // compound key: "group_id + revenue's prefix"
    if (!isset($result[$key])) {
        $result[$key] = ['name' => $key[1] . " Revenue", 'data' => [$v['month'] => $v['amount']]];
    } else {
        $result[$key]['data'][$v['month']] = $v['amount'];
    }
});

print_r(array_values($result));
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => A Revenue
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [4] => 7700
                    [5] => 5000
                )    
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => B Revenue
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [4] => 390
                    [5] => 210
                )
        )
)
```